# jest test to match a returned value as a subset of a hash -without calling the function twice?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I want to match the data structure of a function's returned value against a larger structure (i.e. the returned structure "validates" against a more complete hash). I have a working test that uses toHaveProperty but I'd rather not have to define my object structure in my tests for this particular issue.

What I really want is something that will let me test structure (and not values) that is contained within a larger hash and find a away of not calling the function twice:

```
// ** this would fail if a property value is different **
test('thing returns something matching the structure within types', () => {
    expect(thing()).toBeDefined(
        expect(types).toMatchObject(thing())
    );
});
```

here's the structure:

```
var types = {
    changeSheet:{
        command: ["s", "sheet"],
        options: [],
        required: [],
        sheet_option: true,
    },
    checkIn:{
        command: ["in", "i"],
        options: ["-a", "--at"],
        required: [],
        sheet_option: false,
    },
    checkOut:{
        command: ["out", "o"],
        options: ["-a", "--at"],
        required: [],
        sheet_option: true,
    }
};
```

Here's the function I'm wanting to test:

```
function thing() {
    return {changeSheet: {
        command: ["s", "sheet"],
        options: [],
        required: [],
        sheet_option: false,
    }};
}
```

Notice changeSheet.sheet_option is different from the return value vs the 'types' hash. Is there a jest matching mechanism that will check my structure and ignore the values or am I stuck with toHaveProperty()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Jest's `expect` matching tools: http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/expect.html#content

```
expect(thing()).toMatchObject({
  changeSheet: {
    command: expect.arrayContaining([
      expect.any(String),
      expect.any(String)
    ]),
    options: expect.any(Array),
    required: expect.any(Array),
    sheet_option: expect.any(Boolean)
  }
});
```

That said, what you are testing for here is simply structures/typing which might be better accomplished by using a static type checker like TypeScript or Flow.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense and you've pointed out to me that I wasn't testing value types at all. I was really just wanting to use 'types' as a template for key names. In hindsight that is kind of silly without checking for value types. I come from a background of strongly typed languages so, yea, I might be adjusting a little here with javascript world. Thx!